# Express the real root of $x^3-3x+7$ using radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to express the real root of $x^3-3x+7=0$ using radicals.

---

My attempt is contained in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To express the real root of $x^3-3x+7$ using radicals, we can apply Cardano's method:

\begin{align*}
x^3-3x+7=0&,\text{ let } x=u+v,\quad 3uv=3\implies uv=1\\
\implies& (u+v)^3-3(u+v)+7=0\\
\implies& (u^2+2uv+v^2)(u+v)-3(u+v)+7=0\\
\implies& u^3+2u^2v+uv^2+u^2v+2uv^2+v^3-3(u+v)+7=0\\
\implies& u^3 + v^3+uv(3u+3v)-(3u+3v)+7=0\\
\implies& u^3 + v^3+(uv-1)(3u+3v)+7=0\\
\end{align*}
Since $uv=1$ we simplify to:

$$\implies u^3+v^3+7=0$$

Notice also that $uv=1\implies v=\frac1u$

$$\implies u^3+u^{-3}+7=0$$

let $w=u^3$

\begin{align*}
\implies& w+w^{-1}+7=0\\
\implies& w^2+7w+1=0\\
\implies& w=\frac{-7\pm \sqrt{49-4}}{2}\\
\implies& w=\frac{-7\pm 3\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
\end{align*}

Lets take $w=\frac{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}{2}$, then $u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}{2}}$

$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}{2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}{2}}}$$

$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}{2}}+ \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{-7+ 3\sqrt{5}}}\approx -2.426\in \Bbb R$$

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt[3]{-28+12\sqrt5}+\sqrt[3]{-28-12\sqrt5}}2$. That's real.

Comment: Please include your attempt in your question. Because this is not a complete answer to your question. And then delete this answer.

Comment: @Aniket \ I wasn't providing an answer: Makoto seemed to be saying that his real root had gone missing. I was just pointing out that it was there all the time. In other words, the root that he thought was complex actually IS REAL. Thank you, though.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi The comment was not meant for you. It was directed towards the OP.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-28%2B12\sqrt5}%2B\sqrt[3]{-28-12\sqrt5}}2

Why is that real? It seems both cubics are complex?

Comment: @MakotoK.: Just ask Wolfram to evaluate `(-1)^(1/3)` or `\sqrt[3]{-1}` , and see what happens. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian They are both complex in wolfram? Which I thought they were?, admittedly they do take only one of three branches, but even still, surely since $-28+12\sqrt{5} < 0$, $\sqrt[3]{-28+12\sqrt{5}}\in \Bbb C$?

Comment: @MakotoK.: Why exactly would the principal branch of $\sqrt{-\text{whatever}}$ be more complex than $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$ ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Oh god, my bad, thanks!

Comment: @MakotoK.: I meant $\sqrt[3]{-\text{whatever}},~$ sorry for the typo. Anyway, you get the idea.

Comment: @Aniket It is now complete, so no problems.

Comment: @Servaes \ A quantity under a CUBE ROOT radical would have to be divisible by -- $8$ -- before it can be cancelled by an external $2$. Disability by $4$ just doesn't suffice.

Comment: @Makoto K. \ By removing the part of your post lamenting the "loss" of your real root you have presented future archeologists with a mystery: "To what were all these people referring?"

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Can't they 1) Just look at the edit history? 2) appreciate the hopefully now correct answer.

Thank you very much though, you were very helpful!

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: You're absolutely right, I wasn't paying attention too well. I removed the comment.